# Progression in % in a Prime decomposition

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a function to find the Prime decomposers of a number

```
private static final BigInteger two = BigInteger.valueOf(2);

public List<BigInteger> primeDecomp(BigInteger a) {
    // impossible for values lower than 2
    if (a.compareTo(two) < 0) {
        return null;
    }

    // quickly handle even values
    List<BigInteger> result = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
    while (a.and(BigInteger.ONE).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        a = a.shiftRight(1);
        result.add(two);
    }

    // left with odd values
    if (!a.equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        BigInteger b = BigInteger.valueOf(3);
        while (b.compareTo(a) < 0) {
            if (b.isProbablePrime(10)) {
                BigInteger[] dr = a.divideAndRemainder(b);
                if (dr[1].equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
                    result.add(b);
                    a = dr[0];
                }
            }
            b = b.add(two);
        }
        result.add(b); // b will always be prime here...
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to have a progression in % of the operation ?

Comment: Haha do it like windows. At the beginning, write "1 minute left" and set to 85% then do it, then go to 100% - no really-  to do that, you would need to know beforehand how many iterarions you will need. Not sure if that is possible.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit what do you mean by `progression in %`?